# Making .exe to be run on another computer without installation

Tags: vb.net, installation, exe

Is there any way to make an .exe file run on another computer without installation ? .

The app is quite simple without any resources except one picture.

It has one form, one button and on Form_Load it needs to show picture.

Do I need to make an installation for that ?

Comment: just copy your application-executable and the depending libs (which came not from the framework) to another workstation - which should be possible by default if you have installed the right framework on the target-computer

Comment: When you compile the application, the output in the `bin` folder (possibly in a `Release` or `Debug` subfolder) is what would be needed to run the application.  You can just copy that to another computer.  Assuming that computer has the .NET Framework and any other dependencies your application may have, it should run.

Comment: @David thanks for fast answers but in my Relase/Debug folder there is no picture which i mentioned before.

Comment: @1337user: How is that "picture" included with the application in the first place?  How is it referenced by the application?  You need to be specific, we can't see your project.

Comment: Add the picture as a resource in your project and use it in your code like `My.Resources.MyPicture`

Comment: @David added picturebox, used Import. Added picture from my computer and that is all . If you want i can add ss how it looks like

Comment: it also exist Resources and there is the picture

Comment: If you click on the picture in your project and then look at the properties window, what is the value of the "Build Action" property?

Comment: Build Action property is None

Comment: You might try setting it to Embedded Resource.  That way it will be compiled into your exe.  It might affect the way you refer to it in the code however.  Otherwise you will have to distribute the picture along with the exe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, what you need to do is to first add the picture to the project (on the menu system click `Project | Add Existing Item . . .`) if you haven't done that yet, and then click on the file in Solution Explorer and set its Build Action in the Properties Window to "Resource." This will ensure the picture is written into the exe file when you build the application, and you won't have to worry about copying it along with the application.

Select the "Release" build configuration, and then click `Build | Rebuild` on the menu system to have your application copied to the Bin\Release folder of your project folder. From here you can copy and run it on any computer that has .NET installed.